# undefined method `page_leads' + controller show method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, link-to

i am trying to create a list of leads and create a link to show each one details. so i create a controller like that :

```
class LeadsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @leads = Leads.all
  end

  def show
    @leads = Leads.find(params[:id])
  end

  def delete
  end

  private

    def lead_params
      params.require(:lead).permit(:name,:familyname,:email,:mmobile)
    end

end
```

and a route like below :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'
  get 'pages/home' => 'pages#home'
  get 'leads/index'

  resource :leads
  get 'leads/:id/show'=> 'leads#show',:as => :leads_show end
```

but there are one problem and one question :
the question is when i write `{ Leads.find(params[:id]) }` the editor doesn't recognize params[:id] . why?

and when i want to see http://127.0.0.1:3000/leads/index 
i see the error like that :
undefined method `lead_path' for #<#:0x36da5f8>
Extracted source (around line #8):

```
     <td><%= lead.familyname %></td>
   6  <td><%= lead.mobile %></td>
    7 <td><%= lead.email %></td>
    8 <td><%= link_to 'show' ,  lead %></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
<p>Find me in app/views/leads/index.html.erb</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
@lead = Lead.all
@lead = Lead.find(params[:id])
```

Model Name should be always singular, and ccontroller name will be plural

It should be `resources :leads`, and it will create all the seven actions like show, update, create..etc

And you don't have to call `http://127.0.0.1:3000/leads/index` this `http://127.0.0.1:3000/leads`, this will call index page

Can you post your `params`, so that we can see why you are not getting `params[:id]`

Comment: thank you find the problem. it was  {resources :leads} which i unfortunately write {resource: leads} .